# How to plot the count of one specific species per plot_id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe with 35549 rows × 2 columns:

```
    species_id  plot_id
0   NL            2
1   NL            3
2   DM            2
3   DM            7
4   DM            3
.   .             .
.   .             .
```

Now I want to plot the count of any one specific species (let's say NL) per `plot_id`. For example plot_id 2 may have 10 NL species, plot_id 3 may have 5 NL species and so on. So I have to find the count of the species for every `plot_id` and plot it on the histogram.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.species_id, df.plot_id).plot.bar()`?

Comment: works :) can we make it look better? x-axis looks very clustered